Attempt to rewrite a string concatenating function with realloc instead of calloc
I found on the internet a fine string concatenating function and tried to rewrite its else scope with use of realloc as it was written with use of calloc. However, I failed. Most of the time I tried to use my version of this function the STM32 microcontroller reached HardFault_Handler. With the original code that uses calloc I had no problem like this.

I tried to find what was wrong using the debugger built in STM32CubeIDE but to no avail. I don't know if I have some memory leak or if I calculate byte sizes or lengths incorrectly. Every help and suggestion is deeply appreciated.
void concatenateStrings(char **string, const char *stringToAdd) {

    // Reset *str
    if (*string != NULL && stringToAdd == NULL) {
        free(*string);
        *string = NULL;
        return;
    }

    // Initial copy
    if (*string == NULL) {
        *string = calloc(strlen(stringToAdd) + 1, sizeof(char));
        memcpy(*string, stringToAdd, strlen(stringToAdd));
    }
    else { // Append
        //WORKING
        char *tmp = NULL;
        uint16_t stringSize = strlen(*string);
        uint16_t stringToAddSize = strlen(stringToAdd);

        tmp = calloc(stringSize + 1, sizeof(char));
        memcpy(tmp, *string, stringSize);
        *string = calloc(stringSize + stringToAddSize + 1, sizeof(char));
        memcpy(*string, tmp, strlen(tmp));
        memcpy(*string + stringSize, stringToAdd, stringToAddSize);
        free(tmp);

        //NOT WORKING
        /*
        char *tmp = NULL;
        uint16_t stringSize = strlen(*string);
        uint16_t stringToAddSize = strlen(stringToAdd);

        tmp = realloc(*string, (stringSize + stringToAddSize + 1) * sizeof(char));
        //memset(tmp + stringSize, 0, (stringSize + stringToAddSize + 1) * sizeof(char) - stringSize * sizeof(char));
        *string = tmp;
        memcpy(*string + stringSize, stringToAdd, stringToAddSize + 1);
        */
    }
}


EDIT 1
Here is a fragment of code in which I use above function:
char *stringBuffer;
volatile uint8_t canReceivedValue1 = 0;
char *stringBuffer;
char *stringBufferMain;

...

void HAL_CAN_RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback(CAN_HandleTypeDef *hcan) { 

...
    uint16_t sizeForStringBuffer = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d\n\r", canReceivedValue1);

    stringBuffer = (char *)(calloc(sizeForStringBuffer + 1, sizeof(char)));
    snprintf(stringBuffer, sizeForStringBuffer + 1, "%d\n\r", canReceivedValue1);
    concatenateStrings(&stringBufferMain, stringBuffer);
    //HAL_USART_Transmit(&husart6, (const uint8_t *)stringBuffer, (uint16_t)(strlen(stringBuffer)), 1000);
    free(stringBuffer);
    
...

}


EDIT 2
A stack trace shown in STM32CubeIDE:


EDIT 3
The MRE I prepared:
//main.c
#include "main.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Queue.h"
#include "CAN_Lib.h"

#define PROBE_QUEUE_SIZE (200)
#define MAX_ID (16)

Queue canRxQueue;
canStruct canStructure;
volatile uint8_t receivedValue=0;
uint8_t id=1;
Queue *canRxQueues;
char *strBuf=NULL;
char *strBufMain=NULL;

void concatenateStrings(char **string, const char *stringToAdd);

int main(void)
{

    //HAL init, clock init, peripherals inits (including CAN)...

    canRxQueues=(Queue *)malloc(sizeof(Queue)*16); //queues for data from devices
    for (uint8_t i=0; i<16; i++) {
        initQueue(canRxQueues+i, PROBE_QUEUE_SIZE);
    }

    startCAN(&canStructure); //start CAN
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim10); //start timer that sends CAN messages after certain period of time

    while (1) {}
}

//function for receivement data from CAN bus
void HAL_CAN_RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback(CAN_HandleTypeDef *hcan) {

    canGetMessageFifo0(&canStructure); //receive data from CAN bus (it's an array of 8 uint8_t values, something like rVal[8]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8})
    uint8_t _id=(canStructure.rxHeader->ExtId); //id of device from which we receive data
    uint8_t rxLen=8;

    //we assume the received values require one byte to be stored
    for(uint8_t i=0; i<rxLen; i++) { //for every byte of received data...

        receivedValue=*(canStructure.dataReceived+i); //get received value from canStruct where it's stored
        enqueue((canRxQueues+(_id-1)), receivedValue); //put the variable into queue

        //DEBUG//
        if (_id==16) { //we want to debug data only from device with _id equal to 16
            uint16_t strBufSize=snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d\n\r", receivedValue); //size of string to be added to main string
            strBuf=(char *)(calloc(strBufSize+1, sizeof(char))); //allocate space for strBuf
            snprintf(strBuf, strBufSize+1, "%d\n\r", receivedValue); //make string
            concatenateStrings(&strBufMain, strBuf); //add strBuf to strBufMain
            free(strBuf); //deallocate strBuf
        }
        //END OF DEBUG//
    }
    
    //DEBUG//
    if (_id==16) {
        //transfer concatenated string via USART_DMA
        HAL_USART_Transmit_DMA(&husart6, (const uint8_t *)strBufMain, (uint16_t)(strlen(strBufMain)));
        free(strBufMain);
    }
    //END OF DEBUG//
}

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{

    if (htim->Instance==TIM10) { //request data from device
        static uint8_t generalDataRequest[8]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; //data request command
        canSendMessage(&canStructure, generalDataRequest); //send data request
    }
}

void concatenateStrings(char **string, const char *stringToAdd) {

    // Reset *str
    if ( *string!=NULL && stringToAdd==NULL ) {
        free(*string);
        *string=NULL;
        return;
    }

    // Initial copy
    if (*string==NULL) {
        *string=calloc( strlen(stringToAdd)+1, sizeof(char) );
        if (*string==NULL) {
            asm("NOP");
        }
        memcpy(*string, stringToAdd, strlen(stringToAdd));
    }
    else { // Append
        //WORKING
        char *tmp=NULL;
        uint16_t stringSize=strlen(*string);
        uint16_t stringToAddSize=strlen(stringToAdd);

        tmp=calloc( stringSize+1, sizeof(char) );
        memcpy( tmp, *string, stringSize );
        *string=calloc( stringSize+stringToAddSize+1, sizeof(char) );
        memcpy( *string, tmp, strlen(tmp) );
        memcpy( *string + stringSize, stringToAdd, stringToAddSize );
        free(tmp);

        //NOT WORKING
//        char *tmp=NULL;
//        uint16_t stringSize=strlen(*string);
//        uint16_t stringToAddSize=strlen(stringToAdd);
//
//        tmp=realloc(*string, (stringSize+stringToAddSize+1)*sizeof(char));
//        if (tmp==NULL) {
//          asm("NOP");
//        }
//        //memset(tmp+stringSize, 0, (stringSize+stringToAddSize+1)*sizeof(char)-stringSize*sizeof(char));
//      memcpy(tmp + stringSize, stringToAdd, stringToAddSize+1);
//      *string=tmp;
    }
}

//Queue.h
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int value;
} intValue;

typedef struct {
    int begin;
    int end;
    int currentLoad;
    int size;
    intValue *valueArray;
} Queue;

void initQueue(Queue *queue, int queueLimit);
uint8_t enqueue(Queue *queue, int value);
int dequeue(Queue *queue);

//Queue.c
#include "Queue.h"


void initQueue(Queue *queue, int queueLimit) {
    queue->begin=0;
    queue->end=0;
    queue->currentLoad=0;
    queue->size=queueLimit;


    queue->valueArray=(intValue *)calloc(queueLimit, sizeof(intValue));

    memset(queue->valueArray, 0, queueLimit*sizeof(intValue));
}

uint8_t enqueue(Queue *queue, int value) {
    if (queue->currentLoad<queue->size) { //if queue is not full...
        if (queue->end==queue->size) {
            queue->end=0; //end index circles back to the beginning of the queue if it surpasses the queue's size
        }
        queue->valueArray[queue->end].value=value;
        queue->end++;
        queue->currentLoad++;
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1; //queue is full
    }
}

int dequeue(Queue *queue) {
    if (queue->currentLoad>0 || queue->end!=queue->begin) { //if queue is not empty...
        int value=queue->valueArray[queue->begin].value;

        memset(&queue->valueArray[queue->begin], 0, sizeof(intValue)); //free(&queue->valueArray[queue->begin]); could be used if valueArray's memory was allocated dynamically
        queue->begin = (queue->begin + 1) % queue->size; //it circles back to the beginning because of modulo (%) operation
        queue->currentLoad--;
        return value;
    }
    else {
        return -1; //queue is empty
    }
}


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

New edit:
in your code, if you didn't initialize the char *stringBufferMain and then you passed it to your concatenateStrings function. then inside that function, you are checking for if (*string == NULL), but the stringBufferMain will never equal NULL because you didn't assign it to NULL.
check this code that also worked on my device:
int main() {
    //this gave me an error, because it wasn't equal to NULL.
    //char* stringBuffer;
    //char* stringBufferMain;

    //this worked
    char* stringBuffer = NULL;
    char* stringBufferMain = NULL;

    uint16_t sizeForStringBuffer = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d\n\r", 0);
    stringBuffer = (char*)(calloc(sizeForStringBuffer + 1, sizeof(char)));
    snprintf(stringBuffer, sizeForStringBuffer + 1, "%d\n\r", 0);
    concatenateStrings(&stringBufferMain, stringBuffer);
    

    if (stringBuffer != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", stringBuffer);
        free(stringBuffer);
    }

    return 0;
}

so as a result, if you did initialize the stringBufferMain then it must be a literal string and this is why it didn't work, but if you didn't initialize it, then you must assign it to NULL before concatenating
After your edit:
in the place that you call concatenateStrings, you are using char *stringBufferMain then somewhere you initialize it, if the initializing was a literal string. then Modifying string literals is undefined behavior in C because they reside in read-only memory. Instead, you should pass a dynamically allocated string like this:
char* a2;
a2 = _strdup("Hello");
const char* a3 = "world!";

concatenateStrings(&a2, a3);

or do something like the pointer in the examples down below.
Before your edit
I tested your code on my device, and it works perfectly—there's nothing wrong with it. The only suggestion I have is to consider casting the (void*), although I don't think that's the issue. I suspect the problem lies in how you're calling the concatenateStrings function. Here's your code running correctly on my machine:
This is C++:
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

void concatenateStrings(char** string, const char* stringToAdd) {

    // Reset *str
    if (*string != NULL && stringToAdd == NULL) {
        free(*string);
        *string = NULL;
        return;
    }

    // Initial copy
    if (*string == NULL) {
        *string = (char*)calloc(strlen(stringToAdd) + 1, sizeof(char));
        memcpy(*string, stringToAdd, strlen(stringToAdd));
    }
    else {
        char* tmp = NULL;
        uint16_t stringSize = strlen(*string);
        uint16_t stringToAddSize = strlen(stringToAdd);

        tmp = (char*)realloc(*string, (stringSize + stringToAddSize + 1) * sizeof(char));
        *string = tmp;
        memcpy(*string + stringSize, stringToAdd, stringToAddSize + 1);
    }

}

int main() {
    char* a1 = NULL;
    const char* a2 = "Hello ";
    const char* a3 = "world!";

    concatenateStrings(&a1, a2);
    concatenateStrings(&a1, a3);

    if (a1 != NULL) {
        std::cout << a1 << std::endl;
        free(a1);
    }
    // I got the string "Hello world!" correctly.

    return 0;
}

This is C:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void concatenateStrings(char** string, const char* stringToAdd) {

    // Reset *string
    if (*string != NULL && stringToAdd == NULL) {
        free(*string);
        *string = NULL;
        return;
    }

    // Initial copy
    if (*string == NULL) {
        *string = calloc(strlen(stringToAdd) + 1, sizeof(char));
        memcpy(*string, stringToAdd, strlen(stringToAdd));
    }
    else {
        char* tmp = NULL;
        uint16_t stringSize = strlen(*string);
        uint16_t stringToAddSize = strlen(stringToAdd);

        tmp = realloc(*string, (stringSize + stringToAddSize + 1) * sizeof(char));

        //I suggest to add this:
        //if (tmp == NULL) {
        //    free(*string);
        //    *string = NULL;
        //    return;
        //}

        *string = tmp;
        memcpy(*string + stringSize, stringToAdd, stringToAddSize + 1);
    }

}

int main() {
    char* a1 = NULL;
    const char* a2 = "Hello ";
    const char* a3 = "world!";

    concatenateStrings(&a1, a2);
    concatenateStrings(&a1, a3);

    if (a1 != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", a1);
        free(a1);
    }
    // I got the string "Hello world!" correctly.

    return 0;
}


In C you don't need to (and should not) cast the void pointer returned by realloc. In C++ it's another story.

@SupportUkraine Okay let me check using c, and I will come back to you, although I don't think there will be a huge different

@SupportUkraine I added the c code, and it worked fine exactly as your code, check your compiler settings, or debug somewhere else

@HamzaAlAjlouni if you need to cast then you are compiling as C++. Do not argue.

@0___________ bro, it is C -_-

The question is not tagged C++, why don't you provide also Python version and/or Ada?  Why do you use C functions in C++, while C++ functions/operators should have been more applicable.  Use of malloc() or free() is strongly discouraged in C++ where there appropiate operators new and delete.

@LuisColorado I'm keeping the old code for reference because the question has been edited multiple times. I updated my answer to reflect the changes, but I kept the original versions so the person who asked could trace it. plus the CPP code as it was written to reflect the idea btw

If it is not usable anymore, you can also edit your response to eliminate it.

@LuisColorado, to be honest, I was planning to delete all of it once we get a correct answer, but as long as there is no correct answer still, it may help someone who is trying to trace or debug.

Do you think no answer is correct?  8-. !!!!  wow!  so the only correct answer is the one you have posted?

@LuisColorado, I'm not sure why you're reacting this way. I didn't say that no answer is correct. I simply pointed out that the original poster hasn't marked any answer as correct yet, including mine. I haven't even reviewed the other answers thoroughly. Once the correct answer is chosen, I'll remove my initial code and update accordingly. Until then, I believe keeping the original code can be helpful for anyone trying to trace or debug the issue. Let's keep the discussion constructive and focused on finding the solution. try to focus on being scientists a bit.

the poster doesn't mark the correct answer... he marks his favourite, based on his criteria.  The possibility of several answers is there to hold that people can vote their preferred in order to get an approximate to best answer, based on democratic criteria.  Anyway, democracy is sometimes imperfect and doesn't give the truth.  But saying this today is to bet against oneself.

It looks overcomplicated. Writing string appending function is rather simple.
char *concatenateStrings(char *string, const char *stringToAdd) {
   const size_t string_len = string ? strlen(string) : 0;
   const size_t stringToAdd_len = strlen(stringToAdd);
   void *newstring = realloc(string, string_len + stringToAdd_len + 1);
   if (newstring) {
      memcpy(newstring + string_len, stringToAdd, stringToAdd_len + 1);
   }
   return newstring;
}

And you can use it like:
void HAL_CAN_RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback(CAN_HandleTypeDef *hcan) { 

...
    char *stringBuffer = NULL;
    int err = asprintf(&stringBuffer, "%d\n\r", canReceivedValue1);
    if (err < 0) { /* handle error */ };
    void *tmp = concatenateStrings(stringBufferMain, stringBuffer);
    if (tmp == NULL) { /* handle error */ };
    stringBufferMain = tmp;
    //HAL_USART_Transmit(&husart6, (const uint8_t *)stringBuffer, (uint16_t)(strlen(stringBuffer)), 1000);
    free(stringBuffer); 

But overall other parts of code suggests to me there are bigger problems. Firstly, you try to allocate data from an interrupt handler. Then, from the comment it looks like you tried to send the data from an interrupt handler. Then the signal raised while calling _malloc_r rather suggests to me an out of bounds write that conflicts with _malloc_r.
Interrupt handling should be atomic, short, as short as possible, and the "big" work, like allocating memory or constructing strings - should be preferably done by the main thread. This also simplifies debugging and analysis of the code.
As for errors, check your code. Consider using static analysis and enable compiler warnings, like with GCC compiler you can use gcc -fanalyzer -Wall -Wextra. Consider using linters like clang-tidy cppcheck cpplint and others.

Also, IMO assuming that the first string can be safely realloc()'d is a huge design flaw that makes for dangerously bug-prone code.

@AndrewHenle using malloc in small embeeded targets development is more dangerous

@0___________ That doesn't excuse a bad function design that has implicit limits on what can be passed as arguments when there is no way to validate that those invisible requirements are met, especially if those requirements are not met the entire system can crash.

Hi @AndrewHenle I do not understand why assuming that the first argument can be realloced is a design flaw. For me, such a function is fine.

hi @0___________ that is very much true. I am not sure, could be that newlib is not aware of a limit when moving sbrk and malloc actually overwrites memory allocated on stack. I believe a recommendation to allocate memory on stack is in place. OP if you are reading this, consider just char stringBufferMain[2000 /*or other big number*/] and just use snprintf.

I think I will use statically allocated char array. I didn't know that dynamic allocation can do things to memory such as fragmentation.

@KamilCuk char str[] = "some string"; then char *newStr = concatenateStrings( str, "more string" );  Then entire design is flawed.

Hi @AndrewHenle I do not follow. Does existence of an invalid calls is enough to prove a design flaw? If so, I just disagree that it does. I am C programmer, I know what I am doing, providing documentation for a function is enough for others to know what constraints are put on the first argument. I do not feel like your argument is enough to prove "design flaw". The design is what it is. Tracking pointer provenance and managing memory lifetime is part of programming in C, I would expect programmers to be intimately aware of where the memory for pointers comes from and what can be done with it.

@KamilCuk char str[] = "some string"; is not a value that can be passed to realloc().  The concatenateStrings() design blindly assumes any random char * string passed to it can be realloc()'d.

@KamilCuk How do you use -fanalyzer, clang-lint and -Wall -Wextra?

I understand that, however I question why that makes the design flawed. In C almost all functions blindly assume values ranges that can be or can't be passed to them, we have undefined behavior to deal with invalid calls. char str[] = "some string"; strcat(str, "more string") is also invalid, does it make strcat a flawed design? I assume yes. C is C, it has no safety futures and no seat belts and programmers have to be careful on their own.

@inferjus -fanalyzer -Wall -Wextra are GCC compiler options, see gcc documentation and stm32cubemx documentation . And sorry, I meant clang-tidy with it's own documentation. You can find other linters at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#C,_C++ , I have used also cppcheck and cpplint .

@KamilCuk The documentation for strcat() tells you what happens.

A bit nitpicky but if realloc fails, maybe we'd want else newstring = string; to prevent a memory leak. Or, an abort of some sort.

    if (*string == NULL) {
        *string = calloc(strlen(stringToAdd) + 1, sizeof(char));
        memcpy(*string, stringToAdd, strlen(stringToAdd));
    }

Don't use memcpy (or use strlen(stringToAdd)+1 as the length, to include the null character) to copy the string to the allocated value, memcpy doesn't search for a null character so it will not copy but the characters up to the null, but not the null itself.
IMHO, you can do the following, to achieve your target:
    if (*string == NULL) {
        *string = malloc(strlen(stringToAdd) + 1);
        strcpy(*string, stringToAdd);
    }

Unfortunately there's no standard way to detect if a string has been included an appropiate null character at the end.  The compiler does, but if you do what you describe in your sample code, you will lose it in the copied string.  calloc didn't produce a problem because it initializes the memory acquired with null characters first to return.  If the original string had no null character appended, then from just the call to strlen() you will get undefined behavior.
You have also another approach consisting in using strdup() function (#include <string.h>):
    if (*string == NULL) {
        *string = strdup(stringToAdd);
    }

This function comes from BSD systems, but is implemented almost everywhere.  You will be required to free() the pointer, once you are finished with the string.
For the string concatenation problem I recommend you to use snprintf() function.  It returns the actual number of required characters for the resulting string, and truncates it if the buffer is not large enough.  So my proposal is that you use a buffer large enough for the common set of problems (you don't need only to concatenate strings, you can add separators or formatted numbers.
As in:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *concatenateStrings(char *string, const char *stringToAdd)
{   
    size_t src_len = 0, dst_len = strlen(stringToAdd);

    if (string) {
        src_len = strlen(string);
    }

    /* protect old pointer in case realloc returns NULL */
    char *new_string = realloc(string, src_len + dst_len + 1);

    if (!new_string) {
        perror("could not realloc");
        return NULL;
    }

    /* realloc worked! */
    string = new_string;

    strcat(string, stringToAdd);
    return string;
}


int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{   
    char *string = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
                if (i) {
                        string = concatenateStrings(string, ", ");
                }
        string = concatenateStrings(string, argv[i]);
    }
    printf("%s\n", string);
    printf("string length: %zu\n", strlen(string));

    return 0;
}

If you execute this code you will see all command line arguments concatenated in a series of reallocs.
Note: I've changed the interface a bit to avoid the double pointer, but you can easily change it to your original interface if you prefer.  It also allows to check errors and return NULL in case of realloc is not capable of resizing the dynamically allocated string.

Try this:
void concatenateStrings( char **string, const char *stringToAdd )
{
    char *tmp;
    size_t stringSize;
    size_t stringToAddSize;

    if ( stringToAdd == NULL )
    {
        free( *string );
        *string = NULL;
        return;
    }

    stringSize = *string ? strlen( *string ) : 0;
    stringToAddSize = strlen( stringToAdd );

    tmp = realloc( *string, stringSize + stringToAddSize + 1 );
    memcpy( tmp + stringSize, stringToAdd, stringToAddSize + 1 );
    *string = tmp;
}


It's apparently meant to combine freeing and setting the pointer to NULL instead of having the user do free(str); str = NULL;

@i486 The *string != NULL check is unnecessary here and may in fact lead to problems. See comment by SupportUkraine below:

If *string==NULL and stringToAdd==NULL the code would seg-fault. There should be a check for NULL before strlen( stringToAdd );

@SupportUkraine Changed it. But still don't understand why stringToAdd == NULL must free the *string (like original) instead of doing nothing (keep old *string).

@i486 Well, now you kind of changed the functionality of the function. Not sure that's what OP wants.

@SupportUkraine Now it works the same. free( *string ) will do the job if *string != NULL and does nothing otherwise.

@i486 Strictly, we can't know what OP wanted for that case. We can only guess.... or ask OP.

@TedLyngmo, how can you combine free(ptr); ptr = NULL; in a single statement?

@LuisColorado If you are wondering about my top comment: It was to i486 who didn't understand the logic behind the if ( stringToAdd == NULL ) { free( *string ); *string = NULL; return; } part at first. His comment regarding this is now removed, so I'll remove mine to.

@TedLyngmo, thanks!!


Do not use malloc style allocation when working with small embedded targets. The heap is tiny and it will be fragmented in no time. Read about memory pools or other more deterministic algorithms.

Your function is overcomplicated


char *mystrcat (char **dest, const char *src)
{
    char *result = NULL;
    if(dest && src)
    {
        size_t srcLen = strlen(src);
        size_t destLen = *dest ? strlen(*dest) : 0;
        result = realloc(*dest, srcLen + destLen + 1);
        if(result)
        {
            memcpy(result + destLen, src, srcLen+1);
            *dest = result;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

void printdest(const char *dest)
{
    if(dest) printf("'%s'\n", dest);
    else printf("function failed\n");
}


int main(void)
{
    char *dest = NULL;
    printdest(mystrcat(&dest, "Hello"));
    printdest(mystrcat(&dest, " World"));
    printdest(mystrcat(&dest, ""));
    printdest(mystrcat(&dest, NULL));
    printdest(mystrcat(NULL, " World"));
    printdest(mystrcat(NULL, NULL));
}

